# Show that $(x + 2)(2x - 1)(2x + 3)$ is $(4x^2 + 12x^2 + 5x - 6)$. Why is my answer $4x^3 + 4x^2 - 9x - 6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $(x + 2) (2x - 1) (2x + 3)$ is $4x^2 + 12x^2 + 5x - 6$

My answer was $4x^3 + 4x^2 - 9x - 6$, and steps were:

$$2x^2 - x + 4x - 2 (2x + 3)$$
$$2x^2 - 5x - 2 (2x + 3)$$
$$4x^3 + 6x^2 - 10x^2 - 15x - 4x - 6$$
$$4x^3 + 4x^2 - 9x - 6$$

What things did I get wrong in this calculation? I don’t understand the question well enough to be able to understand where I went wrong, let alone why those things I did wrong were wrong, so it would be helpful if you could explain to me both what steps I did wrong, and why it is that they’re wrong.

The question is from p. 6 of the Pearson Edexcel International A-Level student book, and I’m not very proficient in mathematics. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $4x^2 + 12x^2 + 5x - 6$ is definitely wrong, but yours is wroas well.

Comment: As Martin pointed out the right answer is not $4x^2+12x^2+5x-6$, but $4x^3+12x^2+5x-6$.

Answer (score 3):

So, firstly you should use parentheses to keep the order of operations straight, though this didn't actually factor into the errors:

> $$(2x^2 - x + 4x - 2) (2x + 3)$$
> $$(2x^2 - 5x - 2) (2x + 3)$$
> $$4x^3 + 6x^2 - 10x^2 - 15x - 4x - 6$$
> $$4x^3 + 4x^2 - 9x - 6$$

So, in moving from the first line to the second: note that $-x+4x=3x$, not $-5x$, so you should have
$$(2x^2 +3x - 2) (2x + 3)$$

You made a similar error further down: $6x^2 - 10x^2 = -4x^2$ (not the positive version.

Another is that $-15x-4x=-19x$.

Might could do with a review of polynomial addition and how to handle negatives when adding and subtracting.

Comment: *Sweet Home Alabama*